# The 'right way' to overrule attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

My model includes an 'admin' field, which is true or false. It is not on 'attr_accessible' because we don't want a bad guy to be able to trick our controller into giving 'admin' privs to a user.

Because, if I am logged in as an admin in my model, I 'do' want to be able to update any user's record to make or take away admin from them. So... the lack of attr_accessible on admin prevents me from doing so.

Maybe that's not the right way to look at it. What's the right way to handle such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3.2 added a feature that would allow you to do what you're describing. Simply define this in your model:

```
attr_accessible accessible_attributes + [:admin], :as => :admin
```

And then in the controller where you want to assign the admin attribute, do this:

```
User.new(params[:user], :as => :admin)
```

or

```
user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
```

All the attributes that are listed prior to the `attr_accessible` call with `:as => :admin` will be accessible attributes for any Active Record call that supports the `:as => :admin` option.

If you didn't call `accessible_attributes` in that definition, then only the attributes defined there will be accessible.

Comment: How come does this not open up the very security hole we are trying to protect against with the attr_accessible? Because an attacker could fake an http put to that controller and update that field. Otherwise the feature you describe seems right on. Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't open it up because a hacker can't fake a HTTP put to that controller unless they're an admin. If they're not an admin *and* the controller has authorization protection on it (checking if current session is an admin) then it would not allow it. Typical updates won't allow admin to be assigned because they won't use `:as => :admin`.